# Circular UI chooser with canvas

Tags: html, user-interface, mobile, canvas

By touching and dragging a point in the circle, you should be allowed to choose certain values ​​depending on the distance from the points Nx.

I'll explain in the first image you have a point P is at a certain distance from N1 N2 N3 N4 N5.

The more the point P is close to that value will be higher than Nx (expressed as a percentage), but at the same time is far more than the percentage of Nx decreases, when I stop dragging the point P will have a set of values ​​(equal to 100 %) which is the sum of all N values ​​depending on the distance of the point.

This interface as a search interface, that you're looking for something that has these characteristics N1 = N2 = 35% 35% 10% N3 = N4 = N5 = 10% 10%.

Usually you see this interface but for data rappresentation i'll give you an example of a video game where the character has certain characteristics and you are shown with a graph (25% strength, 25% faster and blah blah ...).
Data must not be a show, but it must be a search ......

Other example..

This interface you decide to seek a professional on the basis of skills (the famous N), however, must match the criteria that you say, as seeking a programmer who knows for a 75% design patterns, SEO 5%, 5% GIT and a 15% i don't know .. other .I drag or point P at a particular criterion because I want to seek a professional who knows how to HTML5 and 100% to 0% remaining 4 skills ...

Comment: Everything you have said seems reasonable enough, but what is your question?

Comment: The question is what's the best way to follow working with canvas object or not?
Is there any library that can facilitate this work.
I found these:
http://www.kineticjs.com/
http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/

It seems to be good, I start from these, or try to make everything from scratch?

Comment: You do realize it's not possible to make two attributes strong at the same time using this scheme? You can overcome this by using a polygon at the center instead a point. The scheme you are suggesting may be easily implemented using some CSS and JS. You'll need to use either Canvas or some SVG for more elaborate schemes.

Comment: This was fun: http://jsfiddle.net/ezimir/WugwX/. But @bebraw makes a very good point, creating a "Radar chart" with draggable points would make selection much more precise.